# Can one table has more than one primary key in Django?

Tags: django

I have following table structure.
When I try to migrate, I got following error.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "certificate_light" has more
>   than one primary key

However, I found other [stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011268/can-a-database-table-contains-more-than-one-primary-key) saying that one table can have more than one primary key in RDBMS.
Can anyone know how I can implement table having more than one primary key in Django?

**models.py**

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Zone(models.Model):
    zone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    conditioned=models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Light(models.Model):
    certificate=models.ForeignKey(Certificate, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='certificate')
    zone=models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='lightzone')
    lpd=models.IntegerField()
    sensor=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**Update**
I added detail error message as below.

```
  Applying certificate.0007_auto_20181126_1155...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "certificate_light" has more than one primary key
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django does not support multiple primary key exactly. Instead you can use [unique_togather](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together). For example:

```
class Light(models.Model):
    certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificate, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='certificate')
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='lightzone')
    lpd = models.IntegerField()
    sensor = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('certificate', 'zone'),)
```

Comment: When I implement unique_together, I got django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: certificate_light.id. Could you tell me how I can solve this?

Comment: That means you have multiple Light Object with same `certificate_light`(in db column it should look like `certificate_light_id`) . Remove the duplicates and run the migrations

Comment: After deleting all Light Object, try to run migration and got django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "certificate_light" has more than one primary key again

Comment: please make sure that you don't have multiple fields with `primary_key=True` in your model. Then run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: I made sure and run makemigrations and migrate. But still got same error...

Comment: Ok, in that case can you remove the last 2 migration files(one for 2 primay key and unique togather), then run makemigrations and migrate please? Also where are you getting the error exactly, in migrate command?

Comment: I tried what you said and still got error. I added detail error message above.

Comment: Okay one drastic solution you can try: 1. Delete all migration files from `migrations` folder except `__init__.py`, 2. Delete the SQLite DB 3. run makemigrations and migrate. **But if you want to keep your current data then you should not do that**

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple OneToOne Fields in a model along with default primary key `id`. The OneToOne field also "behaves" like a primary key i.e. Cannot be same for multiple rows. On top of that, you can use `unique_together` to combine the 2 unique fields.